# Kafka producer batch timeout

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

By setting `batch.size` we tell to the producer to batch records until the size of records reaches to that limit, then send them. There is a strange config `linger.ms`, that says if producer want send records but `batch.size` does not reach wait for more.

My question is that how is it possible that producer sends records before the size of record reach to `batch.size`? I think there is a timeout for waiting for batch, if there is some config, what is it?

I set my producer `batch.size` to 16 MB but producer sends records without considering that limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter you are searching for is exactly `linger.ms`.
Its default value is 0 so it means that the producer will send messages as soon as possible (when a sender thread is available) without any delay and even if the `batch.size` isn't reached.
The condition is that the producer starts to send messages when the `batch.size` is reached or the `linger.ms` time is expired. If you want that the producer sends messages only when the `batch.size` is reached you should increase the `linger.ms` time (greater than 0) and being sure that your application is able to produce messages filling the batch before the value set for the `linger.ms` time; only in this case the producer will send messages because the `batch.size` is reached and not why the `linger.ms` is expired. Of course, increasing the `linger.ms` means to add a delay on sending messages when you don't reach the `batch.size` but you want to send the messages in any case.

Comment: tnx for answer, so `batch.size` is actually `max.batch.size`? isn't it?

Comment: Yes you have to consider it as the maximum size of the batch before messages are sent. It can happen before due to `linger.ms` value as explained.